# Why would UITableView delete button text display in spanish?

Tags: ios, uitableview

For some reason the "Delete" button text on a UITableView is showing "Eliminar" instead of delete on an iPad.  I have checked the setting under General -> International -> Language and it says "English".  The setting for "Region Format" is "United States".

The code base is NOT using the "titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath" method, so that can't be the reason.

Any idea why the delete button isn't English?

Comment: Only the delete button or all system generated buttons showing the same effect ? Are you using localization in your app and what is the default language for your app ?

Comment: The rest of the table delete buttons in apps on the ipad do not display spanish text.  They show "Delete" as expected.

Comment: Just checked the .plist file.  "Localization native development region" is set to English, and that seems to be the only language related value in XCode that I can find